# How do I share a Java Project with a JDBC and a SQL connection?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I made a french conjugator GUI using Java. I also created a SQL Database which had all the french verbs that users could pick and choose using SQL Workbench and connected it to the project.

When I tried to share it with my friends, they were able to access the Java project and see the various GUI elements, but none of the conjugations came up.

This is a screenshot that my friends sent me:
[image: Friends testing the program]

However, when I tried the same inputs I got a valid answer as seen here:
[image: My Test of the same Inputs]

What can I do to fix this problem?
Thank you

Comment: Did you share the database,too ?

Comment: Yeah i shared the database as well exported in the .sql format